# Does Florida have a law which states that unmarried women are not allowed to go parachuting on Sundays?

Tags: united-states, law

[KHSB (NBC News)](https://www.kshb.com/news/local-news/water-cooler/no-unmarried-woman-can-parachute-on-sundays-is-just-one-of-floridas-most-bizarre-laws) (2011) has a self-explanatory headline:

> **No unmarried woman can parachute on Sundays is just one of Florida's most bizarre laws**

[CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2009/TRAVEL/04/03/worlds.strangest.laws/) talks about this law in "World's strangest laws" (2009):

> In Florida, single women can't parachute on Sundays.

After digging through the Florida state statutes, I haven't been able to find any evidence of this law. Does this law exist? If so, what statues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Not any more, and it is doubtful there ever was

https://www.nytimes.com/2005/01/26/us/old-law-shielding-a-womans-virtue-faces-an-updating.html

> *Old Law Shielding a Woman's Virtue Faces an Updating*
>
> By SARAH KERSHAWJAN. 26, 2005
>
> SEATTLE, Jan. 25 - It is about time, politicians here are saying, for the state of Washington to catch up with the rest of the world.
>
> **Florida has struck down a law forbidding unmarried women from parachuting on Sundays**. Michigan has done away with a law making it illegal to swear in front of women and children. Texas women no longer face 12 months in prison for adjusting their stockings in public. And the ladies of Maine can now legally tickle a man under the chin with a feather duster.

Also I found this blog: http://floridalaw.blogspot.com/

On it, it says...

> SUNSHINE LAW IS A BIT CLOUDY
>
> OK, so enough with the weird and ridiculous Florida laws for now. (But, FYI, nowhere in the Florida Statutes could I find the single woman/parachuting on Sunday law.)

So this piece of Internet trivia **may** be a myth... an urban legend.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hesitant to believe the NY Times until I see the actual bill which  repealed the prohibition (or the bill that enacted it).

Comment: At least there seems to be consensus that doing so now is legal, whether is was before or not.

Comment: A common pattern--not sure if it's applicable here--would be to describe laws that forbid general things as though they forbid specific ones.  For example, Illinois has a statute which forbids car dealers from selling cars on Sunday to people who were born on the second Thursday after a full moon to a mother who was born on a Wednesday; that same law also forbids car dealers from selling cars to *anyone else* on a Sunday.  If there had been a law which forbade skydiving on Sunday, the law would have forbidden unmarried woman from skydiving on Sunday.